# GroupBy and Pagination not working together CosmosDB

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following class:

```
public class RetailProduct
{
    public string OriginalVersionId { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public DateTime AvailableTo { get; set; }
}
```

And the following query:

```
public async Task<PagedResponse<RetailProduct>> GetAllRetailProducts(string continuationToken, int pageSize = 10)
    {
        var feedOptions = new FeedOptions
        {
            MaxItemCount = pageSize,
            RequestContinuation = continuationToken
        };

        Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _retailProductCollectionName);

        IDocumentQuery<RetailProduct> query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<RetailProduct>(collectionUri, feedOptions)
            .GroupBy(g => g.OriginalVersionId)
            .Select(p => p.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version))
            .Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault())
            .Where(r => r.AvailableTo > DateTime.UtcNow || r.AvailableTo == null)
            .AsDocumentQuery();

        if (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            FeedResponse<RetailProduct> products = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<RetailProduct>();
            return new PagedResponse<RetailProduct>()
            {
                Continuation = products.ResponseContinuation,
                Results = products.ToList()
            };
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The above method will fail, because I am trying to do a `GroupBy` in `CosmosDB`.  If I change it as follow, to do grouping `in-memory`, I will get my result:

```
public async Task<PagedResponse<RetailProduct>> GetAllRetailProducts(string continuationToken, int pageSize = 10)
        {
            var feedOptions = new FeedOptions
            {
                MaxItemCount = pageSize,
                RequestContinuation = continuationToken
            };

            Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _retailProductCollectionName);

            IDocumentQuery<RetailProduct> query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<RetailProduct>(collectionUri, feedOptions).AsDocumentQuery();

            if (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                FeedResponse<RetailProduct> products = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<RetailProduct>();
                var filteredList = products.ToList()
                    .GroupBy(g => g.OriginalVersionId)
                    .Select(p => p.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version))
                    .Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault())
                    .Where(r => r.AvailableTo > DateTime.UtcNow || r.AvailableTo == null);

                return new PagedResponse<RetailProduct>()
                {
                    Continuation = products.ResponseContinuation,
                    Results = filteredList
                };
            }

            return null;
        }
```

The problem is, because I am doing "in-memory" manipulation of the data, the dataset returned does not always contain 10 records anymore, becuase of my filtering.

The only other option I can think of, is to call my function recursively untill the result contains 10 filtered records, and then return, but this will consume lot's of `RU's` and become quite expensive.

Am I missing something, is there another approach I can take?

Comment: Which Cosmos DB Service API are you using?

Comment: @MikeUbezziMSFT SQL Api

Comment: Cosmos DB's core (SQL) API does not currently support `GROUP BY` (though you can vote on it via [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/18561901-add-group-by-support-for-aggregate-functions), which shows that this feature is being worked on).

Comment: @monstertjie_za Did you find a solution for this?